# Catalog list view is limited to 5 results somehow

Tags: catalog, product-list, xml

Magento CE 1.7

Working with another developer's masterpiece...

This site previously had a very small category of only 4 products. They are adding 2 for a total of 6. After adding and enabling the two new additions into the category I can only see 5 products. I can change the positioning of products and see all 6 but there is a limit being applied somewhere.

I first checked catalog.xml for a column limit and found none. Then I checked list.phtml looking for setPageSize or collectionSize attributes and still found nothing. The page they are using to display these selected products is a CMS page so I looked at the layout update XML and didn't see anything. I tried applying a layout update:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
```

Updated indexes, cleared cache. Nothing.

I echoed the collectionSize on the list.phtml to see what the count was and it continues to say 5. I then did a string search for this mysterious 5 on the entire app directory. Combed through it and did not see a result. Again, the products show if I manipulate product position. I also disabled CSS to see if by chance there was an issue with display:none; or anything of that nature.

I suppose the appropriate question is this: What is the very first location in Magento where someone might place a limit on the number of returned catalog results? Thank you.

Comment: How exactly is the CMS page displaying the products?  Is it using a widget?

Comment: Layout Update XML: <reference name="content">
          <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
              <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>11</category_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I'm not being too simple here, but have you checked the configuration in the admin?

System=>Configuration

Open Catalog=>Frontend

then look at 'Products per page on Grid Allowed Values' and 'Products per Page on Grid Default Value'

Comment: You're a genius and I'm an idiot. I completely forgot that there are options within the admin panel for products views. Here I am overthinking it and assuming it was set in the XML files or manually in the PHP. Thank you!